# When passing a contiguous array to a function, is it more preferable to pass a pointer and the size, or a begin-pointer and an end-pointer?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, function-parameter

When designing a function that expects a contiguous array *in the form of a pointer*, should one pass the array using

A.

a pointer and the array's size:

```
void foo(int* arr, size_t size);
```

Or B.

a begin-pointer and an end-pointer:

```
void foo(int* arrBegin, int* arrEnd);
```

Obviously the total size of the parameters are the same in both methods but is there ever a good reason to prefer one over the other? I believe approach A. is the more common one but I see both being used frequently. Could one make more sense in certain contexts, and vice versa? Does one have any drawbacks compared to the other? Or does it just not matter and you should simply choose one approach and stick with it?

Comment: If I'm using the iterator idiom (prevalent in C++ standard library, as adopted from Stepanov's STL), I'd use `template <typename ITER> foo(ITER b, ITER e)`, but if I'm using an array (and only an array), I do either `void foo(int* arr, size_t size)` or `void foo(pair<int*, size_t> view)`.

Comment: I'd go with Eljay's option C too. That way the function will be able to handle ranges where the data is non-contiguous too (if what is done inside the function permits of course).

Comment: There's also [`std::span`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span) to consider.

Comment: If available, `std::span` is the preferred option as it can be formed  from a pointer+size or by a begin+end. Or a range. Or a `std::array`.

Comment: IMHO, using iterators is more flexible than passing an array and the size.  The `std` library functions use iterators, like `std::sort`.

Comment: @JensB It is a too general question that should be closed.

Comment: You could also use a reference to a `std::array`, const if need-be.

Answer (score 0):

There is the general rule of *least surprise*

If I write a function like (Like @Elijay suggests)

```
template<typename RandomIt>
void f(RandomIt first, RandomIt last)...
```

I can be certain that it is well understood by everyone using my function, contiguous container, pointer like argument type etc.

On top of that *first*, and *last* is a shoe-in for pretty much all of the standard library algorithms and containers. Very convenient and easy to understand.

My 2¢.

Answer (score 0):

First of all use of plain C-Style array is discouraged in `C++`. But, if due to some specific reason, you still want to use it then it's your choice and if its only for array then either approach is fine.

I would personally prefer the approach B i.e. the start and end iterator (using iterator instead of bare pointer) approach because it is more instinctive when the data is contiguous.

Also approach B has one **advantage** over approach A - assume, in future, you need to replace the plain C-Style array with container like `vector` or `array` everywhere in your code, the approach B is more flexible because you don't need to change anything in the place from where `foo()` is called.

e.g.
Take first approach - approach A, iterator and size:

`foo()` implementation:

```
template <typename Iterator>
void foo1 (Iterator itrB, std::size_t sz) {
    // iterate over elements
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < sz; ++i) {
        // access element as itrB[i]
        ....
        ....
    }
}
```

If you call `foo()` with plain C-Style array, this is how it would be:

```
    int arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5};

    foo(std::cbegin(arr), sizeof (arr) / sizeof (*arr));
```

Assume, you need to replace the plain C-Style array with `vector`, this is how you need to call:

```
    std::vector<int> arr = {1,2,3,4,5};

    foo(std::cbegin(arr), arr.size());
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

You need to modify the `foo()` call everywhere for array `size` argument.

Same is the case with `array` container.

Now, take the second approach - approach B, start and end iterator:

`foo()` implementation:

```
template <typename Iterator>
void foo (Iterator itrB, Iterator itrE) {
    // iterate over elements
    for (auto b = itrB; b != itrE; ++b) {
        // access element as *b
        ....
        ....
    }
}
```

call `foo()` with plain C-Style array, this is how it would be:

```
    int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

    foo (std::cbegin(arr), std::cend(arr));
```

with `vector` :

```
    std::vector<int> arr = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
```

No change is required in the `foo()` call, the same call statement will work:

```
    foo (std::cbegin(arr), std::cend(arr));
```

---

Note that `std::cbegin()` and `std::cend()` introduced in `C++14`, if you are using `C++11` then replace them with `std::begin()` and `std::end()` respectively.